# Access specific properties in Angular from mapped and piped HTTP response to dedicated Object

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and TypeScript, but I'm trying to write application, which will make some operations based on retrieved response from REST service.

I decided to use [ng-swagger-gen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-swagger-gen) in order to generate services and models from my REST API. Models are created as interfaces, **dummy-response.ts**:

```
export interface DummyResponse {

   name?: string;
   order?: number;
}
```

Service **dummy-service.ts** has two methods:

```
getDummyResponse(): __Observable<__StrictHttpResponse<DummyResponse>> {
  // some code with headers, params etc...
  return this.http.request<any>(req).pipe(
    __filter(_r => _r instanceof HttpResponse),
    __map((_r) => {
      return _r as __StrictHttpResponse<DummyResponse>;
    })
  );
}

getDummy(): __Observable<DummyResponse> {
  return this.getDummyResponse().pipe(
   __map(_r => _r.body as DummyResponse)
  );
}
```

Now in my other class, I'm trying to access "name" field and perform some operations with it. But I have problem with accessing this value:

```
private resp: DummyResponse;

constructor(private dummyService: DummyService) {}

getName() {
  this.dummyService.getDummy().subscribe(data => {
    let json = JSON.stringify(data);
    this.resp = data;
    console.log(json); // {"dummyResponse":{"name":"default","order":1}}
    console.log(this.resp); // {dummyResponse: {…}}
                            //  > dummyResponse: {name: "default", order: 1}
                            //  > __proto__: Object
    console.log(this.resp.name); // undefined
    console.log(this.resp.dummyResponse.name); // default
  });
}
```

How to properly map this *data* into *DummyResponse* object and access one of its fields? And even if the last console prints the correct value, Angular is throwing an error about not existing property on type *DummyResponse* (which is correct). But I don't understand why *data* are not real *DummyResponse*, where even Visual Studio Code is saying that data is type of *DummyResponse*.

What I'm missing here? Could someone explain me what's going on?

Comment: vs code trusts you when you say that "heeey... I know that this data which is coming is of type `DummyResponse`". There is no runtime checks for this.

Comment: Ah I see, but how to retrieve there what I need?

Comment: @AJT82 but why data are not the type of DummyResponse? Why I can't access its fields?

Comment: well, seems your response has a `dummyResponse` object with the data you want, so you'd need to do: `_r.body.dummyResponse as DummyResponse`.

Comment: @AJT82 I agree with you, but as I mentioned in my post, after compilation I see error in terminal that property `dummyResponse` does not exist on type `DummyResponse`. So from one way its correct, form other not.

Comment: oh, right. The issue is that you are telling that you are returning `getDummyResponse(): __Observable<__StrictHttpResponse<DummyResponse>>` when in fact that is not what you are returning. You **could** bypass this with doing `getDummyResponse(): __Observable<__StrictHttpResponse<any>>`. But you could make a model for it: `export interface MyType { dummyResponse: DummyResponse }`. `MyType` is a poor name, so choose better ;) BTW, I like interfaces instead of classes, especially if you don't have class specific methods, just my personal opinion.